# Wrong Fragment receives onLongPress listener

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` inside which I insert `Fragment`'s dynamically, currently I am using a single `Fragment` which I am then inserting in `ViewPager` by using a `for` loop.

Within that `Fragment` I have a `GestureListener` in which I am capturing various touch event by the user, one of them being onLongPress

```
@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {
    Log.e("ID AND STATE",
    String.format("%s %s", ID, mState));
    if (mState == 4)
        homeActivity.openContextMenu(mLayout);
    else if (mState == 8)
        showDialog();
    else if (mState == 5)
        showDialog();
    else if (mState == 1)
        showDialog();
    else if (mState == 2)
        showDialog();
    }
```

Based on the value of `mState` I want to show a `ContextMenu` or some `Dialog` with text, but that is not happening; instead I am receiving wrong `ID` and `mState` values when I long press on some `Fragment`, usually that `ID` and `mState` value is from the neighbour `Fragment`.

I tried using `getUserVisibleHint()` to no avail, I've included it in various levels to see if it has any effect but it doesn't.

What is the issue here, how can this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue, I was setting `onTouch` listener in `onCreateView` of `Fragment`, it turns out that there is a mysterious method named `setUserVisibleHint` which is never mentioned in official Android docs as if we were supposed to discover it ourselves; any how I had to call my `onTouch` inside that overridden `setUserVisibleHint`, the code follows...

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        Log.d("On setUserVisibleHint", String.format("%s %s %s",
                "ON setUserVisibleHint CALLED", ID, mState));
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                new MyGestureDetector());
        cardImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
            }
        });
    }
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}
```